# Which is correct and why?

Tags: sentence-construction, comparison

I haven’t seen you in a million years.
I haven’t seen you since a million years.

Which is correct and why?

Answer (score 1):

To avoid the hyperbole of *a million years*, change the period to a realistic time-frame **days/weeks/months** so that the question becomes:

Is it better to use the preposition **in** or **for** after saying:

> I haven't seen you **in** or **for** days/weeks/months

A quick check using Google ngram shows that both prepositions are used in this context in much the same measure.

Historically, **for** has been more popular but in the last 30 years **in** has nudged ahead.

So take your choice.

However, you can't say **since a million years**.

**Since** always requires a direct or indirect time reference as in:

> Since Christmas, since your wedding, since the turn of the century

but NOT **since two years** or **since two years ago**

Comment: _Since two years ago_ is OK. _Since_ requires a definite past starting point and the postpositional phrase _two years ago_ (but not the durational phrase _two years_) defines such a starting point. It has to be bracketed `[since [[two years] ago]]`, though; a postpositional phrase inside a prepositional phrase.

Comment: @JohnLawler  Granted! But, like haggis, I wouldn't recommend it to my friends!